# Group 15 elements reactivity towards water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why only tin in group 14 elements react with water and others do not?

Comment: Under what conditions? Steam oxidation is used in silicon integrated circuit production (well, probably not on leading-edge CMOS anymore).